# Linking with Google filament gltfio

Tags: compiler-errors, linker, google-filament

I'm attempting to link with gltfio and google filament, but I'm getting link errors about undefined `SHADER_PACKAGING` and such. What's the correct way to link the many filament libraries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We may never know, since CMake is awful to read and decipher. However, using linker groups can sort the dependencies and deduce the correct order. I've been told it's slow, but not slower than spending hours figuring this mess out

```
target_link_directories(again-filament PUBLIC ${filament-lib-dir})

# Just listed everything and deleted what I didn't want
set(filament-libs
filament
#filamat_lite # filamat lite has opengl only
filamat
backend
#basis_transcoder
bluegl
bluevk
filabridge
filaflat
utils
geometry
smol-v
ibl
gltfio
gltfio_core
stb
zstd
#ibl-lite
vkshaders
shaders
uberarchive
#uberzlib
filameshio
#civetweb
dracodec
camutils
#filament-iblprefilter
#image
#ktxreader
matdbg
meshoptimizer
mikktspace
#viewer
)
# magic string to enable link groups
target_link_libraries(again-filament PUBLIC "$<LINK_GROUP:RESCAN,${filament-libs}>")
```